# How to enable item language fallback in a multi-site solution for particular sites?

Tags: multilingual, multisite, language-fallback

[Here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/language_fallback/setting_up/enable_and_set_up_language_fallback) the Sitecore documentation says:

> In multisite environments where you only want to enable language fallback on a subset of the websites, you need to *create a specific shell site for each website where you want the language fallback feature enabled.*

What should be the configuration for the the *specific shell site*?

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/language_fallback/setting_up/enable_and_set_up_language_fallback#_Enable_site-level_language
`Enable site-level language fallback` section

Comment: yes, I found this exactly, just the quoted text makes me confused, how should it be configured.

Comment: I enabled language fallback few times and I never created any site specific `shell` sites. `shell` can be only one. For me this `You must enable the attributes on the shell and on each of the relevant websites.` says everything. I might be wrong but I think that quoted part of the docs is incorrect.

Comment: It is not. Partial answer here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/what-is-the-use-of-shell-website-in-the-sitecore-languagefallback-config-file

Comment: Thanks. That make sense but like you said doing this may not ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short; I probably wouldn't do it.

#### Background

The issue here is; that Language Fallback is a mechanism that not only affects your content delivery; it also affects behaviour inside the Sitecore clients themselves (Experience Editor and Content Editor).

These both run in the context of the `"shell"` site.

For a solution wide approach, see the answer already given here: [What is the use of "shell" website in the Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config file](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/what-is-the-use-of-shell-website-in-the-sitecore-languagefallback-config-file)

The issue is; once you enable Language Fallback for `"shell"`, it will take effect on Experience Editor and Content Editor - *regardless of what site you are actually editing*. There is no way around this; this is just how these Sitecore client interfaces work.

#### What it means

So essentially; if you want different behaviour *by-site*, you are going to have to configure separate Content Editing (Sitecore Client) environments per site. The way to do this, would be to configure additional `"shell"` sites.

It's easy enough to do, as such. At least on paper. You can define multiple sites inheriting from your `"shell"` site (as shown in the linked answer), and additionally configure them with a `hostName` attribute to respond to. The end result being; you go to `www.site1.com/sitecore`, the `"shell"` site without Language Fallback gets triggered. And then `www.site2.com/sitecore` with Language Fallback enabled.

But your editors would need to log in and out using different host names, and I don't really think they're going to appreciate this.

Comment: Another approach could be to split the templates. Let's say we have a `Fallback News` template and `Not Fallback News`. It's a workaround but a possible solution. What do you think?

Comment: That could be, but wasn't your question though ;-)